# Выкидывает с сайта на планшетах

Tags: php, wordpress, javascript

Всем привет!

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться... Сделал [сайт](http://50cc-moto.com/) на Wordpress, все как обычно, но почему-то на планшетах с него выкидывает, то на обновление FLV плеера (видео там вообще нет), то вообще полностью из браузера. Причем на разных планшетах... На одном после каждого 15-20 перехода по сайту выкидывает... В чем может быть дело? Подскажите... На компе все нормально!

Answer (score 1):

На сайте вирус. Проверяй исходники на наличие вредоносного кода, а так-же загляни в файл .htaccess и проверь на наличие редиректов на сторонние сайты.